# Packaging synthesized design as netlist for use in future designs

Tags: fpga, vhdl, quartus

I am attempting to create a synthesized netlist of an FSM to help decrease my synthesis time, but I've been unable to get Quartus to generate the correct output files or even find any resources on what the correct output files should be. In the provided screenshot I only have FSM.vhd included in the project because Quartus Prime Lite does not support incremental synthesis, so I think I need to synthesize the FSM by itself.

For the most part, I've been working in the task window trying to see where there might be settings related to netlist generation, but anything mentioning netlists in the synthesis stage just brings me to the RTL viewer, FSM viewer, or the technology map.
[image: Current Quartus setup with Tasks menu]

I also tried playing with the EDA Netlist Writer settings, but couldn't find any settings pertaining to the generation of output files.

Moving to the output files being generated by Quartus, currently, aside from the report and summary files, I am generating .sof, .pof, .jdi, .sld, and .vho files. I know the .pof and .sof are binaries for programming the FPGA and from what I understand .jdi is the jtag report. The .sld file appears to be XML which, of what I have been able to generate, leaves only .vho. I tried to use the .vho file noting that it did have references to the FSM entity, but this gave some errors about the declaration of FSM. Upon further research I saw on Intel's website that .vho files cannot be compiled.

Am I missing some synthesis file that can be re-compiled? I have seen reference online to .edf files that sound similar to what I am looking for, but I really am not sure what kind of file I should be looking for or how to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Not possible in the free version of Quartus.

The term you are looking for is exporting of "post-synthesis netlists". This generates a `.qxp` file for a design partition, which can be a subset of a project, or the entire project.

These are generated using the "Export Project as Design Partition" command.

However as design partitions and incremental compilation are unavailable due to license restrictions in the Lite version of Quartus, it is not possible to export netlists. You would require a license for the Standard edition.

Comment: I actually might be able to access a Standard edition license, just not a pro edition. Would you mind elaborating how to do this in the SE License?